# RGB LED crashing my arduino board? (Bug found, just need explanation)

Tags: arduino

So I notice my arduino boards were crashing after the first 60 seconds (halt on Serial) so I decided to randomly comment out blocks of code to see if I could identify the culprit. Luckily, I did!

This is my hardware setup:

```
Board: Arduino Mega
Pin 16,17: EC sensor 
Pin 14,15: pH sensor
Pin 2,3,4: RGB LED
```

I have definitively identified `initRGB` and `displayGreen()`, `displayBlue()` and `displayRed()` is crashing my board. Why?

Code:

```
#include <Adafruit_CC3000.h>
#include <ccspi.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "utility/debug.h"
#include <Base64.h>


int RGB_RED = 4;
int RGB_GREEN = 3;
int RGB_BLUE = 2;


String ecSensorString = "";
String phSensorString = "";

...

// Set this on if you want to supply an IP address directly
#define IP_NOT_DOMAIN   true
#define PORT            8080

// This corresponds to 192.168.1.117
#define IP_1 192
#define IP_2 168
#define IP_3 1
#define IP_4 117

#define WEBSITE      "blah.appspot.com"
#define WEBPAGE      "/api/points/new/"

// This is needed for http basic authorization
String serial="serial";
String token="token";

uint32_t ip;


void setup() {
  //initRGB();
  Serial.begin(9600);

  ecSensorString.reserve(30);
  phSensorString.reserve(30);

  initSensors();
  initWireless();

  Serial.println("Setup Complete");
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Loop begins");

  Serial.print("Free RAM: ");
  Serial.println(getFreeRam(), DEC);

  getEC();
  getPH();
  Serial.println("Sensors reading completed");

  createPoint(ecSensorString, phSensorString);
  Serial.println("createPoint completed");

  delay(10*1000);
  Serial.println("delay completed");
}

/*
void initRGB() {
  pinMode(RGB_RED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_GREEN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RGB_BLUE, OUTPUT);
  //displayBlue();     
}


void displayBlue() {
  analogWrite(RGB_RED, 0);
  analogWrite(RGB_GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(RGB_BLUE, 255);
}

void displayRed() {
  analogWrite(RGB_RED, 255);
  analogWrite(RGB_GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(RGB_BLUE, 0);
}

void displayGreen() {
  analogWrite(RGB_RED, 0);
  analogWrite(RGB_GREEN, 255);
  analogWrite(RGB_BLUE, 0);
}
*/

void initWireless() {
  /* Initialise the module */
  if (!cc3000.begin()) {
    Serial.println(F("Couldn't begin()! Check your wiring?"));
    //displayRed();
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Initialization Complete"));

  Serial.print(F("Attempting to connect to "));
  Serial.println(WLAN_SSID);
  if (!cc3000.connectToAP(WLAN_SSID, WLAN_PASS, WLAN_SECURITY)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed!"));
    //displayRed();
    while(1);
  }
  Serial.println(F("Wireless Connected!"));

  /* Wait for DHCP to complete */
  while (!cc3000.checkDHCP()) {
    delay(100); // ToDo: Insert a DHCP timeout!
  }
  Serial.println(F("DHCP Requested!"));

  if (IP_NOT_DOMAIN) {
    ip = cc3000.IP2U32(IP_1, IP_2, IP_3, IP_4);
  } else {
    ip = 0;
    // Try looking up the website's IP address
    while (ip == 0) {
      if (! cc3000.getHostByName(WEBSITE, &ip)) {
        Serial.println(F("Couldn't resolve!"));
      }
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}


void initSensors() {
  Serial2.begin(38400);
  Serial3.begin(38400);

  // Tell the EC sensors to stop continuous mode
  Serial2.print("c,0\r");
  // Tell the pH sensor to stop all readings
  Serial3.print("E\r");

  // TODO: EC sensor's first reading is always empty, possibly delay?
}


void createPoint(String ec, String ph) {
  if (ec && ph) {
    postPointToServer("ec=" + ec + "&ph=" + ph);
  } else if (ec) {
    postPointToServer("ec=" + ec);
  } else if (ph) {
    postPointToServer("ph=" + ph);
  } else {
    Serial.println("createPoint: null");
  }
}


void postPointToServer(String data) {
  Serial.print("postPointToServer:");
  Serial.println(data);

  // Http Basic Authorization
  String auth_raw = serial + ":" + token;
  char auth_input[200];
  char auth_output[200];
  auth_raw.toCharArray(auth_input, auth_raw.length() + 1);
  base64_encode(auth_output, auth_input, auth_raw.length());

  Adafruit_CC3000_Client www = cc3000.connectTCP(ip, PORT);

  if (www.connected()) {
    www.fastrprint(F("POST ")); www.fastrprint(WEBPAGE); www.fastrprint(F(" HTTP/1.1\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Host: ")); www.fastrprint(WEBSITE); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Authorization: Basic ")); www.fastrprint(auth_output); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.fastrprint(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));

    char len_c[7];
    itoa(data.length(), len_c, 10);
    www.fastrprint(F("Content-Length: ")); www.fastrprint(len_c); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));

    // Extra empty line for post arguments
    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));

    char data_c[200];
    data.toCharArray(data_c, data.length() + 1);
    www.fastrprint(data_c); www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));

    www.fastrprint(F("\r\n"));
    www.println();

    //displayGreen();
  } else {
    Serial.println(F("Connection failed"));
    //displayRed();
  }

  www.close();
}


void getEC() {
  ecSensorString = "";
  Serial2.print("r\r");       // Read only 1

  char inchar;
  while (Serial2.available()) {
    inchar = (char)Serial2.read();
    if (inchar != '\r') {
      ecSensorString += inchar;
    }
  }

  Serial.print("getEC:");
  Serial.println(ecSensorString);
}


void getPH() {
  phSensorString = "";
  Serial3.print("R\r");       // Read only 1

  char inchar;
  while (Serial3.available()) {
    inchar = (char)Serial3.read();
    if (inchar != '\r') {
      phSensorString += inchar;
    }
  }

  Serial.print("getPH:");
  Serial.println(phSensorString);
}
```

Comment: Theory: Your LED is drawing too much current?

Comment: @Dithermaster That's not true because if I commented the code out the RGB block of my code the LED is still on and the board doesnt' crashes

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you could provide the schematics as well. How are things connected?

When you write "halt on Serial" you mean that the last you see as sign of any activity is a printout on the serial port? Have you tried to blink the onboard LED within the loop()?